# Write in html file with PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to write in html file with PHP but is written only the last:
Please help me:

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('my_server', 'user', 'password')
    or die("Can't");
$db = mysql_select_db('database')
    or die ("Can't select");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM News LIMIT 3';
$retval = mysql_query($sql,$link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";
        $content = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <div class="block">';
            $content .='<a href="="">'.$row['Title'].'</a>';
            $content .='<div class="date">';
            $content .=$row['Date'];
            $content .='</div>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        $filename ="footer.html";
        @unlink($filename);
        $handle = fopen("footer.html", 'w+');
        echo $row['Title'].'<br>';
        if ($handle) 
        {
            if (!fwrite($handle, $content))
            die("cant' write");
        }
}
    ?>
```

Write only the last query..
I tried but did not receive...

Comment: you overwriting the $content every time ,because it is in the loop

Comment: I solved it, $filename ="footer.html";
 $handle = fopen("footer.html", 'w+'); must be above while ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to put initial $content variable & file write part outside for loop.

```
$content = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";
        $content .= '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <div class="block">';
            $content .='<a href="="">'.$row['Title'].'</a>';
            $content .='<div class="date">';
            $content .=$row['Date'];
            $content .='</div>';
        $content .= '</div>';

}
$filename ="footer.html";
@unlink($filename);
$handle = fopen("footer.html", 'w+');
echo $row['Title'].'<br>';
if ($handle) 
{
    if (!fwrite($handle, $content))
    die("cant' write");
}
```